# Is embedding the EAX nonce inside the Associated Data considered safe?

Tags: encryption, aes

As the nonce bits would be used twice in that case, does that break EAX security? The examples I've seen using EAX have separated the nonce from the Associated Data, but to me it makes more sense to have the nonce be a part of it.

http://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/eax.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nonce is already authenticated. There is absolutely no reason or need for you to do this. Whether or not it reduces security, I can't say. However, it certainly doesn't *improve* security.

> but to me it makes more sense to have the nonce be a part of [the associated data]

I would, as a general rule, trust the cryptographers responsible for designing EAX over your own gut feelings.

Comment: That makes sense. No need to improve the security further, just didn't want to reduce it by accident. I'll make sure the nonce is kept outside the associated data. Thanks!